# C++ compile error with templates

Tags: c++, templates, syntax

I have this function:

```
template <typename T>
List<T>::ListNode *List<T>::find(int index) const
{
    if ( (index < 1) || (index > getLength()) )
        return NULL;
    else
    {
        ListNode *cur = head;
        for (int skip = 1; skip < index; ++skip)
            cur = cur->next;
        return cur;
    }
}
```

That is giving me these two errors, each on the second line:

```
expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '*' token
expected `;' before '*' token
```

All my other methods that use templates work just fine. I think the problem is that my syntax where I am calling my ListNode struct is wrong. I had this working without templates earlier and now I'm trying to implement it with templates and I am getting these errors.

Comment: is getLength() using a type specific method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should be

```
template <typename T>
typename List<T>::ListNode *List<T>::find(int index) const
// ...
```

`typename` tells the compiler that `List<T>::ListNode` represents a type. When inside a template, there is a parsing ambiguity when `::` is encountered. You therefore have to use the `typename` keyword when whatever follows `::` is a type.

Comment: @Max: I was going to but you have to wait 15 or so minutes to do so.